# Git commit in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab

I have my ownbuilt gitlab server that i have created a project which i then clone to my visual studio where i then add a solution and when im trying to commit and create a remote repository the commit option does not show in the solution option list??? i am using visual studio 2019. I really do not understand why in anyway anyone that has an answer please do so i need help with this!! :D thx in advance...
[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the team explorer tab, click the **home button**. (the one with the cute little house).

Then, click on "Changes" and you should be able to commit. You should also be able to push by clicking "Sync" and "Push" afterwards.

If those options does not appear or does not work, i would advise to try to re-set up your git environment with the command line (in a git bash for example) before trying again.

More on that here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Gonna test it will give answer and maybe another question if none of theese work'